# Expression OrderBy Then By returning (Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>)

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have a repository class as follows. Here my problem is in the GetSelected Method

```cs
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    protected readonly DbContext Db;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;
    
    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Db = context;
        DbSet = Db.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    //CRUD Operations

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetSelected(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to sort the Department by providing parameters on the fly as follows.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DepartmentsController : LookupBaseController<Department>
{

    private readonly IUowLookups UowLookups;

    public DepartmentsController(IUowLookups uowLookups) : base(uowLookups)
    {
        UowLookups = uowLookups;
    }

    [HttpPost] //Improvise on this
    [Route("getorderd")]
    public IEnumerable<Department> GetSelectedValues(List<string> ids)
    {
        
        var sortColumns = new Dictionary<string, Sorter>();

        sortColumns.Add("Code", new Sorter(1, SortDirection.Ascending));
        sortColumns.Add("Name", new Sorter(2, SortDirection.Ascending));

        IQueryable<Department> coll = Enumerable.Empty<Department>().AsQueryable();


        var sortExp2 = ExpressionBuilder.OrderByColumns<Department>(coll, sortColumns);

        var data = UowLookups.Repository<Department>().GetSelected(null, sortExp2 )
                                                                        
        return data.ToList();
    }
}
```

I have the following code (found in StackOverflow) that's working fine. But I want the following code to return (`Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>`) instead of the collection. I also prefer not to pass the collection to this method, instead, it should take the `TEntity` I pass as the collection. Is it doable?

```cs
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderByColumns<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> collection, IDictionary<string, Sorter> sortedColumns)
{
    // Basically sortedColumns contains the columns user wants to sort by, and 
    // the sorting direction.
    // For my screenshot, the sortedColumns looks like
    // [
    //     { "cassette", { Order = 1, Direction = SortDirection.Ascending } },
    //     { "slotNumber", { Order = 2, Direction = SortDirection.Ascending } }
    // ]

    bool firstTime = true;

    // The type that represents each row in the table
    var itemType = typeof(TEntity);

    // Name the parameter passed into the lamda "x", of the type TModel
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(itemType, "x");

    // Loop through the sorted columns to build the expression tree
    foreach (var sortedColumn in sortedColumns.OrderBy(sc => sc.Value.Order))
    {
        // Get the property from the TModel, based on the key
        var prop = Expression.Property(parameter, sortedColumn.Key);

        // Build something like x => x.Cassette or x => x.SlotNumber
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, parameter);

        // Based on the sorting direction, get the right method
        string method = String.Empty;
        if (firstTime)
        {
            method = sortedColumn.Value.Direction == SortDirection.Ascending
                ? "OrderBy"
                : "OrderByDescending";

            firstTime = false;
        }
        else
        {
            method = sortedColumn.Value.Direction == SortDirection.Ascending
                ? "ThenBy"
                : "ThenByDescending";
        }

        // itemType is the type of the TModel
        // exp.Body.Type is the type of the property. Again, for Cassette, it's
        //     a String. For SlotNumber, it's a Double.
        Type[] types = new Type[] { itemType, exp.Body.Type };

        // Build the call expression
        // It will look something like:
        //     OrderBy*(x => x.Cassette) or Order*(x => x.SlotNumber)
        //     ThenBy*(x => x.Cassette) or ThenBy*(x => x.SlotNumber)
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types,
            collection.Expression, exp);

        // Now you can run the expression against the collection
        collection = collection.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(mce);
    }

    return collection;
}
```

Comment: This is a very odd request, feels like an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a Repository<TEntity> class  with a method GetData that accepts a parameter Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy. I want to pass the result of the above function (collection) to that method(GetData) as the parameter value for parameter orderBy.

Comment: Post sample of usage. Words is not enough.

Comment: Hello Danyliv, Thank you for the effort in helping me. I have a Repository class which have a method as below

Comment: I am trying to share my code, but it's not fitting in the comment. Do you know how to share the code. Sorry for this question I am new to this

Comment: @Jacob, just edit original question and add sample of the usage.

Comment: Hello Danyliv, it's done as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple:

```cs
public static Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> CreateOrderByFunc<TEntity>(IDictionary<string, Sorter> sortedColumns)
{
   return q => (IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>)q.OrderByColumns(sortedColumns);
}
```

Comment: Why do you complicate your application by such repositories? For me is just wasting time and complicating debugging.

Comment: Thankyou Danyliv.It worked. I wasted almost three days to get this thing working. May I know some good resources where I can understand the details of the Expression tree, LINQ etc? Once again Thankyou very much. Regarding the Repository pattern, it was told that this is the best approach to be taken. Even some MS sites were recommending this.

Comment: @Jacob: I reply to you here instead of via Email then. I was confused about what you want at first. My solution you referred to about creating the Expression Tree dynamically (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55857105/2410655) works best when you have no idea which column(s) the user wants to order. But in your case, it looks like you've already known which to sort (code, name). It doesn't make sense to do it with dynamic expression tree approach then, because you can put the sorting on the collection your repositories return, on `IQueryable`.

Comment: Thank you, David. Your first post I copied above is superb. In fact, that was the only post I could find after several days of searching that includes OrderByand ThenBy dynamically. Thank you for taking the time to reply, but I can't find any email from you including in my SPAM folders. Can you please forward it again? Since you wrote the original code, May I ask what do you suggest for my scenario